# Get the style of the font file using QFont

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Is there a command in QFont where I can get the style of the font. I figured out how to get the family name of the font file but not the specific style of the file. I found a command which returns the entire list of styles associated with the font family.

```
    styleList = QtGui.QFontDatabase.styles(fontFamilyName)
```

I need the exact style of the specific font file. For example, if I give arialb.ttf as an input, I should be getting family name: Arial; style: Bold. Any ideas?

---

But I am trying for the fonts which is not installed in the machine. This is my code.

```
    fontFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\abc.otf" 
    fontdb = QtGui.QFontDatabase() 
    id = fontdb.addApplicationFont(fontFile) 
    family = fontdb.applicationFontFamiles(id) 
    font = QtGui.QFont(family[0]) 
    print font.styleName()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always use [QFontInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontinfo.html) to get accurate information about a font. A [QFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html) will only show what was *requested*, rather than what the system was actually able to provide:

```
>>> font = QtGui.QFont('Arial')
>>> font.family()
'Arial'
>>> fontinfo = QtGui.QFontInfo(font)
>>> fontinfo.family()
'Helvetica'
```

I don't have "Arial" installed on my system, so the font resolves to the nearest equivalent, which is "Helvetica". To get the style, either do this:

```
>>> fontinfo.styleName()
'Regular'
```

or just query the properties directly:

```
>>> fontinfo.bold()
False
>>> fontinfo.italic()
False
```

Comment: But I am trying for the fonts which is not installed in the machine. This is my code.



      `fontFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\abc.otf"
       fontdb = QtGui.QFontDatabase()
       id = fontdb.addApplicationFont(fontFile)
       family = fontdb.applicationFontFamiles(id)
       font = QtGui.QFont(family[0])
       print font.styleName()`

Comment: @GowthamanIlango. None of that makes any difference. You need to use `QFontInfo`, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: I tried QFontInfo and still no luck. I am getting null string as output. fontinfo.bold() and fontinfo.italic() are always false. I tried fontinfo.weight() which is always returning 50 no matter what font I use.

Comment: @GowthamanIlango. It may be because you are on Windows. Can you give a link to a font so that I can test it?